# Why does a for-comp inside of a for-comp not work

Tags: scala, playframework

The following works fine:

```
def show(id: Int) = myAction asyc {

  for {
    users <- userService.getAll()
    locations <- locationService.getByUsers(users)
  } yield {
    Ok("hi")
  }

}
```

But if I do this:

```
 for {
    users <- userService.getAll()
    locations <- locationService.getByUsers(users)
  } yield {
    for {
      f1 <- ...
      f2 <- ....
    } yield {
      Ok("hi")
    }
  }
```

I get a type mismatch error:

```
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
[error]           f1 <- ....
```

Hoping someone can explain this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding type annotations might help make clearer what's going on:

```
val result: Future[Future[Result]] = for {
  users <- userService.getAll()
  locations <- locationService.getByUsers(users)
} yield {
  val innerResult: Future[Result] = for {
    f1 <- ...
    f2 <- ....
  } yield {
    Ok("hi")
  }
  innerResult
}
```

By yielding a `Future[Result]` (`innerResult`), you're causing the outermost `for` to be of type `Future[Future[Result]]`.

We know that `result` is going to have to be of type Future[???] (determined by the type of the first generator, `userService.getAll()`). It winds up being a `Future[Future[Result]]` because you yield a `Future[Result]`.

The solution is to yield a `Result` intead:

```
def foo(users: Seq[User], locations: Seq[Location]): Future[Result] = {
  for {
    f1 <- ...
    f2 <- ....
  } yield {
    Ok("hi")
  }
}

for {
  users <- userService.getAll()
  locations <- locationService.getByUsers(users)
  result <- foo(users, locations)
} yield result
```