# Explanation on the error with for comprehension and co-variance

Tags: scala, for-loop, covariant

## Question

Would like to get assistance to understand the cause of the error. The original is from [Coursera Scala Design Functional Random Generators](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun2/lecture/S7NQA/lecture-1-3-functional-random-generators).

### Task

With the factories for random int and random boolean, trying to implement a random tree factory.

```
trait Factory[+T] {
self => // alias of 'this'
    def generate: T
    def map[S](f: T => S): Factory[S] = new Factory[S] { 
        def generate = f(self.generate) 
    }
    def flatMap[S](f: T => Factory[S]): Factory[S] = new Factory[S] { 
        def generate = f(self.generate).generate 
    }
}
val intFactory = new Factory[Int] {
    val rand = new java.util.Random
    def generate = rand.nextInt()
}
val boolFactory = intFactory.map(i => i > 0)
```

### Problem

The implementation in the 1st block causes the error but if it changed into the 2nd block, it does not. I believe `Factory[+T]` meant that `Factory[Inner]` and `Factory[Leaf]` could be both treated as `Factory[Tree]`.

I have no idea why the same if expression in for block is OK but it is not OK in yield block. I appreciate explanations.

```
trait Tree
case class Inner(left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
case class Leaf(x: Int) extends Tree

def leafFactory: Factory[Leaf] = intFactory.map(i => new Leaf(i))
def innerFactory: Factory[Inner] = new Factory[Inner] {
  def generate = new Inner(treeFactory.generate, treeFactory.generate)
}

def treeFactory: Factory[Tree] = for {
  isLeaf <- boolFactory
} yield if (isLeaf) leafFactory else innerFactory
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    type mismatch; found : Factory[Inner] required: Tree
                    type mismatch; found : Factory[Leaf]  required: Tree
```

However, below works.

```
def treeFactory: Factory[Tree] = for {
  isLeaf <- boolFactory
  tree   <- if (isLeaf) leafFactory else innerFactory
} yield tree
```

Comment: If you replace `Tree` with `Result` and `Factory` with `Future`, this is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386424/why-does-a-for-comp-inside-of-a-for-comp-not-work/34386532

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea why the same if expression in for block is OK but it is
>   not OK in yield block

Because they are translated differently by the compiler. The former example is translated into:

```
boolFactory.flatMap((isLeaf: Boolean) => if (isLeaf) leafFactory else innerFactor)
```

Which yields the expected `Factory[Tree]`, while the latter is being translated to:

```
boolFactory.map((isLeaf: Boolean) => if (isLeaf) leafFactory else innerFactory)
```

Which yields a `Factory[Factory[Tree]]`, not a `Factory[Tree]`, thus not conforming to your method signature. This isn't about covariance, but rather how for comprehension translates these statements differently.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need a bit more time to fully understand how flatMap part works.